# How to dynamically pass SQLite data to arraylist in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to dynamically pass all the data from SQLite Table Aluno to the arraylist alunosinf but its not working.

If i try manually it works, example:

```
alunolv student_Tom = new alunolv(123, "Tom Silva", "Avenue Tree", 91234567, "tom@example.pt");

alunolv student_Bob = new alunolv(321, "Bob Pereira", "Street One", 9876554, "bob@example.pt");

alunosinf.add(student_Tom);

alunosinf.add(student_Bob);
```

=========================================

My try to dynamically pass the SQLite data to the arraylist alunosinf:

SQLite query:

```
public Cursor mostraAlunos () {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Aluno", null);
    return c;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
lv_Contactos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContactos);

List<alunolv> alunosinf = new ArrayList<alunolv>();

baseDeDados db;

public static final int numeroAluno = Integer.parseInt("numero");
public static final String nomeAluno = "nome";
public static final String moradaAluno = "morada";
public static final int telefoneAluno = Integer.parseInt("telefone");
public static final String emailAluno = "email";

Cursor alunos_cursor = db.mostraAlunos();

if (alunos_cursor != null && alunos_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
            int numeroNovo = alunos_cursor.getInt(alunos_cursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(numeroAluno)));

            String nomeNovo = alunos_cursor.getString(alunos_cursor.getColumnIndex(nomeAluno));

            String moradaNova = alunos_cursor.getString(alunos_cursor.getColumnIndex(moradaAluno));

            int telefoneNovo = alunos_cursor.getInt(alunos_cursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(telefoneAluno)));

            String emailNovo = alunos_cursor.getString(alunos_cursor.getColumnIndex(emailAluno));


            alunolv aluno = new alunolv(numeroNovo, nomeNovo, moradaNova, telefoneNovo, emailNovo);


            alunosinf.add(aluno);

        } while (alunos_cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<alunolv> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<alunolv>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alunosinf);

    lv_Contactos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Constructor:

```
public class alunolv {

int numero;

public int getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}


String nome;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}


String morada;

public String getMorada() {
    return morada;
}

public void setMorada(String morada) {
    this.morada = morada;
}


int telefone;

public int getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(int telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}


String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public alunolv(int n, String no, String m, int t, String e){
    numero = n;
    nome = no;
    morada = m;
    telefone = t;
    email = e;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return nome;
}

public String ListarContacto(){
    return String.valueOf(numero) + " " + nome + " " + morada + " " + String.valueOf(telefone) + " " + email;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mixed English and Portuguese so it was difficult to understand.

But my suggestion is that you create a method to make a select in the database and return your list of "Alunos".

Avoid return the Cursor. You have to return what really matters (the "Aluno" list).

**See improved method:**

```
    public List<alunolv> findAll() {

    List<alunolv> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String columns[] = new String[]{
            "numero",
            "nome",
            "morada",
            "telefone",
            "email"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query("Aluno", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            alunolv aluno = new alunolv();
            aluno.setNumero(cursor.getInt(0));
            aluno.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
            aluno.setMorada(cursor.getString(2));
            aluno.setTelefone(cursor.getInt(3));
            aluno.setEmail(cursor.getString(4));

            list.add(aluno);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. It gives error (red color) at the word query, and i have also the SQLite mostraAlunos () not in the MainActivity. When i try to remove the return c (cursor) it gives error.